# Creating HTML tag in react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not extending component class, trying to use `usestate` to manage state. Now I want to add a person component on certain conditions to `personList` variable inside the method `togglePersonsHanler`.
I'm expecting a list of HTML tags to be added like

```
<person name="person1" age=31>
<person name="person2" age=26>
<person name="person3" age=35>
```

but on console log, I'm getting `personList` as below

`{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)type: "div"key: nullref: nullprops: {children: Array(3)}_owner: null_store: {validated: false}_self: null_source: {fileName: "D:\data\react\my-app\src\App.js", lineNumber: 72, columnNumber: 7}`

and person tag is not getting added to DOM, any advice, please

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

const App = props => {    
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState({
    persons: [
      {name: "person1", age:31},
      {name: "person2", age:26},
      {name: "person3", age:25}
    ],
    other: "some Other Value"

  } );

  const [otherState,setOtherState]=useState({otherState :'some other value'});
  const [showPersonsState,setShowPersonsState]=useState({showPersons :false});

    let personList=null;
    const togglePersonsHanler =() =>{
      personList=null;
      setShowPersonsState(
        {showPersons : !showPersonsState.showPersons}
      )
      console.log(showPersonsState.showPersons);
      if(showPersonsState.showPersons){
        personList=(
      <div>{personState.persons.map (person =>{
        return <person name={person.name} age={person.age}/>
      }
      )}</div>

        );
      }
      console.log(personList);
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> HI, I'm the react app</h1>
      <button 
      //onClick={switchNameHandler.bind(this,'Gopu Ravi')} 
      onClick={togglePersonsHanler}
      style={style}> Toggle Person </button>
      { personList }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mapping the object literals by using them *as* an html tag. You likely meant to use the imported `Person` component.

```
<div>
  {personState.persons.map (person => (
    <Person name={person.name} age={person.age}/>
  )}
</div>
```

And to fix a react-key warning since all mapped elements need unique keys, add a key prop with a value that is unique to the data in the array, like name:

```
<div>
  {personState.persons.map (person => (
    <Person key={name} name={person.name} age={person.age}/>
  )}
</div>
```

To correctly toggle the display of the "personList":

1. Conditionally render the mapped `persons` array if `showPersonsState` is `true`
2. Simplify `showPersonsState` state to simply be the boolean value
3. Use functional state update to correctly toggle `showPersonsState` from previous state

Updated component code

```
const App = props => {
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState({
    persons: [
      { name: "person1", age: 31 },
      { name: "person2", age: 26 },
      { name: "person3", age: 25 }
    ],
    other: "some Other Value"
  });

  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState({
    otherState: "some other value"
  });
  const [showPersonsState, setShowPersonsState] = useState(false);

  const togglePersonsHandler = () => setShowPersonsState(show => !show);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> HI, I'm the react app</h1>
      <button onClick={togglePersonsHandler}>Toggle Person</button>
      {showPersonsState &&
        personState.persons.map(({ age, name }) => (
          <Person key={`${name}`} name={name} age={age} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit vigorous-leftpad-d571m]

Comment: Thanks Drew. The view is not using the updated personList , how can i achieve to use updated personList. Note: I'm not extending the `component` class

Comment: @upog `personList` isn't a state or prop value, so react doesn't consider it when the component needs to be rerendered. Are you simply trying to toggle viewing the `personList` (really `personState.persons`) when the button is clicked that toggler `showPersonsState`?